# InputStreamResource equivalent without Spring

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an angular project and there's this module which allows to download some files from the server, the thing is those files are large and they can't be kept in memory so I need a functionality like InputStreamResource in spring, I can't use this one because the project is not using spring at the moment, I've been looking for something similar in Java but I cant find anything.

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(input);
response.setContent(resource);
response.setLength(file.length());
```

This is basically what I did with a spring project, so is there any similar library for doing the same?

Currently I'm using JavaEE for business and RestEasy for rest services.

Comment: For doing the same... with which framework/technology?

Comment: Hey, just edited the question, I'm using JavaEE for logic/business

Comment: So you're using JAX-RS (which is the standard that RestEasy implements). Have you googled for "JAX-RS streaming"?

Comment: JAX-RS is part of Java EE, BTW. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html